# Countable and uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I was solving some real analysis questions and came to this one. Which of the following is an uncountable subset of $\Bbb R^2$?

1. $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x\in\Bbb Q\lor x+y\in\Bbb Q\}$
2. $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x\in\Bbb Q\land y\in\Bbb Q\}$
3. $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x\in\Bbb Q\lor y\in\Bbb Q\}$
4. $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x\in\Bbb Q\lor y^2\in\Bbb Q\}$

Comment: I guess some people are downvoting your question. Next time, add a bit more about what you have tried previously, and where you encountered the question. That would help your case.

Comment: I am new to this so just learning how to use this

Comment: I totally understand. I wish people explained things a bit more before they started downvoting posts. We all have a first time, and it helps us improve the next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Note that  all the sets in the question has cardinality less than or equal to $\mathbb{R^2}$ (and we know $\mathbb{R^2}$ is equinumerous with $\mathbb{R}$)

(1) $S=\{(x,y)|x \in \mathbb{Q}\ or\ x+y\in \mathbb{Q}\}$
Here consider the map:
$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S$$
defined by $\ $ $f(x)=(0,x)$.
Therefore $f$ is an injection. Hence S becomes uncountable.
Furthermore, $|S|=|\mathbb{R}|$.

(2) This set is countable. (!check).

(3)  $S=\{(x,y)|x \in \mathbb{Q}\ or\ y\in \mathbb{Q}\}$
Here consider the map:
$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S$$
defined by $\ $ $f(x)=(x,0)$.
Therefore $f$ is an injection. Hence S becomes uncountable.
Furthermore, $|S|=|\mathbb{R}|$.

(4)  $S=\{(x,y)|x \in \mathbb{Q}\ or\ y^2\in \mathbb{Q}\}$
Here consider the map:
$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S$$
defined by $\ $ $f(x)=(x,0)$.
Therefore $f$ is an injection. Hence S becomes uncountable.
Furthermore, $|S|=|\mathbb{R}|$.

Answer (score 0):

1) Think of $(x=.5+a,y=.5-a)$ for any irrational (or real) number $a$.

2) You should be able to do this.. Similar proof as that of all rationals being countable.

3) Think of $(x=a,y=.5)$ for any real number $a$.

4) How many rational numbers are there? Can you map them to their square-roots in a bijection? 
Can you use (2) to take it here on?

Comment: Ok now i understood 2,3,4.. And i got that 3 is uncountable since real numbers are uncountable. Am i right?. Can u explain 1

Comment: For any $a$, $x+y=.5\in\mathbb Q$, but how many possible $a$s can we produce?

Comment: Only one.. So it is countable

Comment: Why only 1? You can fill it with *any* real number!